# Convert Any to Long in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, classcastexception

I am trying to convert the `Any` type of an Object to `Long`, but it is showing the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Here I want to cast the `any` to `Long` like below:

```
    fun getMyLongValue(vararg any: Any) : Long {
    return when(val tmp = any.first()) {
        is Number -> tmp.toLong()
        else -> throw Exception("not a number")
    }
}
```

I am passing params to it like:

```
    fun main() { 
    val param1 = 10
    val param2 = 20
    println(getMyValue(param1.toLong(), param2.toLong())) 
}

fun getMyValue(vararg any: Any): Long {
    return getMyLongValue(any)
}
```

Comment: `getMyLongValue(15, 10)` could complain that `java.lang.Integer` can not be cast to `Long` but how are you getting `java.lang.Object[]` is beyond me. Old Kotlin SDK version?

Comment: No, it's latest

Comment: Will `getMyLongValue(15L, 10L)` work?

Comment: I am passing Int values but I want to cast to Long. Then why it's not allowing? Even I pass Long still the same issue.

Comment: Here is the link to it https://pl.kotl.in/ZzKOfpPXM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am passing Int values but I want to cast to Long. Then why it's not allowing?

Because of [boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). `Any` corresponds to Java `Object`, so all primitives are boxed when passed to `getMyLongValue`. And you can't cast a boxed `Int` (`java.lang.Integer`) to `Long`. You'll need to handle primitives separately, or use the fact that boxed `Int`/`Long`/etc. extend `Number`, e.g.

```
fun getMyLongValue(vararg any: Any) : Long {
    return when(val tmp = any.first()) {
        is Number -> tmp.toLong()
        else -> throw Exception("not a number") // or do something else reasonable for your case
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This problem is not related to converting to `Long`. When you write

```
fun getMyLongValue(vararg any: Any) { ... }

fun getMyValue(vararg any: Any): Long {
    return getMyLongValue(any)
}
```

you pass the entire `any` from `getMyValue` as a single argument (of type `Array<Any>`). To pass `10` and `15` (or other arguments of `getMyValue`) separately, you need to use [the spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
fun getMyValue(vararg any: Any): Long {
    return getMyLongValue(*any)
}
```

Comment: Even it is a number still, it is throwing the exception

Comment: @ShylendraMadda I can just show that it works here https://pl.kotl.in/4R6R9ckye

Comment: See the edit (and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the future, because your question was missing an important part).

Comment: Got it simply I need to keep `*` in front of any param. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't just use `as Long` here. Because it would always fail unless you pass `Long` parameter.

You should `toLong()` function to convert. But it's not method of `Any`. So you will have to get rid of `Any` type specification.

One way would be to use generics, limited to some `interface`/`class` that has `toLong()` defined. Like [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html).

```
fun <T: Number> getMyLongValue(vararg any: T) : Long {
    val myVal = any.first().toLong()
    return myVal
}
```

It will definetely work for

```
getMyLongValue(15, 10)
```

But may not work for your real data, if it would have non-numeric "input".

---

Also, why are you using `vararg` if you just using the first element?

Either drop it, or handle all values:

```
fun <T: Number> getMyLongValue(vararg any: T) : List<Long> {
    val myVal = any.map { it.toLong() }
    return myVal
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, link to it: https://pl.kotl.in/ZzKOfpPXM

Comment: @ShylendraMadda, ok, your code you can add more type checks to the `when`, like `String`, and others that have `toLong()` implemented.

Comment: I want to know why it is failing w=even I pass Long type. For now I wanna check with Long.